# Mapproxy shows tiles in wrong position

Tags: proxy, gis, mapbox, stamen-maps

I am using Mapproxy to display map http://maps.stamen.com/toner/#3/49.78/-4.04. But the tiles are shown in wrong position.
For example:

[Map without zoom:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL7Ac.png)

[Map with one level zoom:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn3Bn.png)

More zoomed, the image looks even more odd.

Mapproxy configuration:

```
layers: 
  - name: StamenToner
    title: StamenMap
    sources: [stamen_cache]  

caches:
  stamen_cache:
    grids: [stamen_grid]
    sources: [stamen_wmts]

sources:  
  stamen_wmts:
    type: tile
    url: http://tile.stamen.com/toner/%(z)s/%(y)s/%(x)s.png
    grid: stamen_grid

grids:
    stamen_grid:
        srs: 'EPSG:3857'
        origin: 'nw'
        tile_size: [512, 512]
```

I have no idea why the tiles are in wrong position when zoomed. Any suggestions.

Comment: are you using openlayers with mapproxy? if yes, please share how you rendered map using mapproxy & openlayer

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with MapProxy==1.13.0

```
layers:
  - name: StamenToner
    title: StamenMap
    sources: [stamen_cache]

caches:
  stamen_cache:
    sources: [stamen_tiles]

sources:
  stamen_tiles:
    type: tile
    url: http://tile.stamen.com/toner/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png
    grid: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
```

**Note**: Check the URL parameter order.  `/z/x/y` rather than `/z/y/x`; according to [the docs](http://maps.stamen.com/#toner/14/30.2223/-97.8366):

> Many applications and libraries understand the notion of map URL templates. These are ours:
>
> - [http://tile.stamen.com/toner/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](http://tile.stamen.com/toner/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)
> - [http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg](http://tile.stamen.com/terrain/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.jpg)
> - [http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg](http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.jpg)